# ExceptionInInitializerError - java.lang.RuntimeException: could not locate data -> Conexión a MongoDB con spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

llevo más de 2 días investigando para identificar el error en este proyecto pero no he tenido mucho éxito. No se si estoy haciendo mal la consulta, pero no encontré mucha información relacionada al error que encentro.

Estoy realizando una conexión de java a mongodb en entorno local usando `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`. He buscado documentación y ejemplos para construir mi clase MongoConfig. Además, hago uso de `spring-cloud-starter-config`, que permite que mi archivo .yml lo pueda referenciar desde github.
Sin embargo, al ejecutar el aplicativo como SprinBootApplication, me genera una excepción `ExceptionInInitializerError` en MongoTemplate.
Les compartiré el .yml, las clases que utilizo y la excepción generada:

En el archivo .yml estoy declarando no solo la URI, sino también los datos de conexión, aunque no los uso todos.

```
#HTTP Server
server:
  port: ${PORT:7000}

#Discovery Server Access
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
  instance:
    status-page-url-path: /infoMiClase
    health-check-url-path: /healthMiClase
    metadata-map:
       app-owner: Georgina
       description: Testing Microservice

spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/db_name
      database: db_name
      port: 27017
      host: localhost
      username: user
      password: pass
```

Esta es la clase MongoConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.x.package")
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String uri;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        //conString = "mongodb://user:passw@localhost:port/db_name
        return MongoClients.create(uri);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.x.package";
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory dbFactoryBean() throws Exception {
        MongoDbFactory dbFactoryBean = new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(mongoClient(), database);
        return dbFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

Ya he probado con eliminar algunos de los métodos, agregar otros.. y aun asi el error generado es idéntico.

Por último, esta es mi clase Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MyclassApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyclassApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Y en la consola se muestra el log con la excepción generada:

```
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:16 [restartedMain] ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:5000
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:17 [restartedMain] ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Located environment: name=x.package, profiles=[default], label=null, version=1099c5eddeec953f0a0f7ae271107c9bfef376e5, state=null
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:17 [restartedMain] PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration - Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}]}
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:18 [restartedMain] RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:18 [restartedMain] RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 77ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interfaces.
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:18 [restartedMain] GenericScope - BeanFactory id=93880b7e-3900-3ff7-a938-2947239e7c50
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:19 [restartedMain] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$73f21667] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:19 [restartedMain] TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 7000 (http)
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:19 [restartedMain] Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7000"]
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:19 [restartedMain] StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:19 [restartedMain] StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:19 [restartedMain] [/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:19 [restartedMain] ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2168 ms
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:19 [restartedMain] cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:20 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e40eae3e4e5e75d67d95154', description='null'}-localhost:27017] connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:41}] to localhost:27017
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:20 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e40eae3e4e5e75d67d95154', description='null'}-localhost:27017] cluster - Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 13]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=3904400}
[WARN ] 2020-02-10 00:32:20 [restartedMain] AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyclassController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'MyclassService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyclassService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'MyclassRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyclassRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/x/package/config/MongoConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:20 [restartedMain] StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
[INFO ] 2020-02-10 00:32:20 [restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

[ERROR] 2020-02-10 00:32:20 [restartedMain] SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyclassController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'MyclassService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyclassService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'MyclassRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyclassRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/x/package/config/MongoConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyclassService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'MyclassRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyclassRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/x/package/config/MongoConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyclassRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/x/package/config/MongoConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/x/package/config/MongoConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.text.RBTableBuilder.build(RBTableBuilder.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.text.RBCollationTables.<init>(RBCollationTables.java:83) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.<init>(RuleBasedCollator.java:300) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.<init>(RuleBasedCollator.java:281) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.CollatorProviderImpl.getInstance(CollatorProviderImpl.java:106) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.text.Collator.getInstance(Collator.java:242) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.text.Collator.getInstance(Collator.java:224) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.GeoConverters.<clinit>(GeoConverters.java:71) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions.<clinit>(MongoCustomConversions.java:55) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:2852) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:258) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:234) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.x.package.config.MongoConfig.mongoTemplate(MongoConfig.java:53) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.x.package.config.MongoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$745df10d.CGLIB$mongoTemplate$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.x.package.config.MongoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$745df10d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3f5863e6.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.x.package.config.MongoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$745df10d.mongoTemplate(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not locate data
    at sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerImpl.<clinit>(NormalizerImpl.java:60) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.text.RBTableBuilder.build(RBTableBuilder.java:107) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.text.RBCollationTables.<init>(RBCollationTables.java:83) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.<init>(RuleBasedCollator.java:300) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.<init>(RuleBasedCollator.java:281) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.util.locale.provider.CollatorProviderImpl.getInstance(CollatorProviderImpl.java:106) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.text.Collator.getInstance(Collator.java:242) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.text.Collator.getInstance(Collator.java:224) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.GeoConverters.<clinit>(GeoConverters.java:71) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions.<clinit>(MongoCustomConversions.java:55) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:2852) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:258) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:234) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.x.package.config.MongoConfig.mongoTemplate(MongoConfig.java:53) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.x.package.config.MongoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$745df10d.CGLIB$mongoTemplate$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.x.package.config.MongoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$745df10d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3f5863e6.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.x.package.config.MongoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$745df10d.mongoTemplate(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at 
    ... 24 more
```

Como se puede ver en la línea 15 y 16 de la consola, si se realiza la conexión con Mongo, pero luego se genera el error y se termina el proceso. Estoy usando `spring-boot-starter-parent` con versión `2.2.3.RELEASE`.

Le ha pasado a alguien algo similar? Yo sospecho que es una configuración mínima que estoy pasando por alto y no me doy cuenta :( 
Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: que tal si quitas la base de datos en la uri `uri: mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/db_name` o quitas `database` al config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este [post](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/keystore-corrupt.36052/) me dio una sospecha de cual podría ser un error: 
Sucede que la instalación de java "se ha corrompido" o algo por el estilo, pues solo **eliminando la instalación de jdk.8.0_221 por jdk.8.0_241 y actualizando el JAVA_HOME** ha funcionado.
Sin ningún cambio adicional en código.

El secreto para acercarme a la solución fue buscar el porque se lanza esta excepción: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not locate data`, la cual es el origen del resto de excepciones.

Dejo la respuesta por si alguien más tiene un problema tan raro como el mío :(